# When 3 random variables are independent, the sum of the first two is independent from the third

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be independent real random variables. That is, for all Borel measurable sets $S_1, S_2, S_3 \subset \mathbb{R}$ it holds true that:

$P(X_1 \in S_1 \text{ and } X_2 \in S_2 \text{ and } X_3 \in S_3) = P(X_1 \in S_1)P(X_2 \in S_2)P(X_3 \in S_3)$.

Now we define $Z = X_1 + X_2$. How can we prove that $Z$ is independent from $X_3$?

Comment: Could show it very easily with the characteristic functions of the random variables, but you probably want an answer with a more set theoretic flavour?

Comment: Note that we need to only choose certain kinds of Borel sets above, which generate $S$. Then, you can use the proof that $X_1 + X_2$ is a random variable, which uses rational numbers, to break up the probabilities into only those involving $X_1,X_2,X_3$, and use independence.

Comment: The problem is to show that if the three random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are independent then the two random variables $(X_1,X_2),\  X_3$ are independent.